# Trying to install OpenCV with Matplotlab

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am attempting to install OpenCV on my linux computerI followed this installation guide:

**Linux / Mac Users:**

pip3 install numpy or apt-get install python3-numpy. You may need to apt-get install python3-pip.

pip3 install matplotlib or apt-get install python3-matplotlib.

apt-get install python-OpenCV.

...

everything installs, except the last one Python-OpenCV
error:

```
  E: unable to locate package python-OpenCV
```

and then when I run python in the terminal and try to run:

```
 import matplotlab
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   file "stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Importerror: no module named 'matlabplot'
```

meanwhile

```
import cv2
```

&

```
import numpy
```

run without error and seem to work, this is also the case when I run a .py file that calls for importing those three.

Any information will be helpful, i am fairly new to python and linux :)

Comment: For one, you probably want to `import matplotlib`not `matlabplot` or `matplotlab`

Comment: In Linux mint, the package name is all lower case - `apt-get install python-opencv` so yours might be too.  (Generally Linux is _very_ fussy about the case of every command - always a gotcha for people new to Linux).

Comment: did you mean https://matplotlib.org ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), there are download for Windows, Linux and Mac. Installation is easy.

I would suggest you download Anaconda2. 
Then install with command  (on Linux) (more [documentation](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux) on installation)

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

There are cv2, mathplotlib pre-install

[image: pic]

***NOTE**: I trying to find **mathplotlab** or **matlabplot** with Python on Google but can't find any. Instead, Google suggests **mathplotlib**. Perhaps you mistake library name

Answer (score 0):

The openCV 3 package is called `opencv-python` in pip3 (python3). For python2, replace `pip3` with `pip` and `python3-opencv` with `python-opencv`

**Mac OS (OS X) / Linux**

```
$ pip3 install -U opencv-python
```

or as mentioned by @GregHNZ on **linux**

```
$ apt-get install python3-opencv
```

All versions are imported with `import cv2` inside python scripts.

---

Probably you can import `cv2`and `numpy`because it is installed for dependency reasons by other packages. 
 
As in comments already mentioned probably you mean `matplotlib`